# jersey-client - NoSuchMethodError: MultivaluedMap.addAll

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey-client

I try to use jersey-client in my web app, but I get the following exception.
Can anybody help?

Thanks!

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V 
(loaded from file:/D:/Users/xxxxxxx/.m2/repository/com/ibm/was/srt/j2ee/8.5.5.9/j2ee-8.5.5.9.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@bb0a768e)
 called from class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest 
(loaded from file:/D:/Users/ xxxxxxx /.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.26/jersey-client-2.26.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@bb0a768e).

at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:222)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:60)
```

Comment: Do you have some Jersey 1.x dependencies in your project?

Comment: No, I have no other Jersey dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrong version in JEE 6, this ist the right one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```